# Javascript Dynamically insert script element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert the following

```
<script language="javascript">
var x = '-----BEGIN SOME-----\n
-----END SOME-----\n;';
</script>
```

I know how to do when using a "src" attribute. But in my case, I want to append some variable x in the script.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://xyz";
$("head").append(s);
```

Comment: can you be more clear?

Comment: I just need the script tag which has the var x =''' to be printed/rendred in my html

Comment: In your html, in which element?

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. There are very little cases where this type of things is necessary, explain better what your are trying to do, so we can give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.innerHTML = 'alert("Hey there... you just appended this script to the body");';
   $("body").append( script );
```

use innerHTML to dynamically add scripts to your element.

Comment: Is the above possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you mean is that you want to generate a `<script>` tag with variables inside. To do this you can use jQuery:

```
$('html').append('<script>console.log("hello world");</script>')
```

This will display `hello world` in the console. Of course you can switch the JavaScript code to whatever you would like.